# How calculate the marks using switch in react?

Tags: reactjs

I created the few questions page I want calculate marks when click the submit button  but when I click submit button marks didn't show.
This my code code . In this code I get the values from the checkbox and input to switch case and calculate the marks but marks doesn't show and not redirect to  '/questions/markspage/${marks}' this page.

code

```
function InAnswers() {
  const history = useHistory();
  const [answers, setAnswers] = useState('');
  const [question, setQuestion] = useState('');
  const [dayWord, setDayWord] = useState(''); //1
  const [seeObject, setSeeObject] = useState(''); //2
  const [identifyObject, setIdentifyObject] = useState(''); //3
  const [identifyColor, setIdentifyColor] = useState(''); //4
  const [firstWord, setFirstWord] = useState(''); //5
  const [marks, setMarks] = useState(''); //5

  async function submitMarks(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var marks = 0;
    switch (marks) {
      case 'wordday' == 'wordmore5':
        setMarks(marks + 10);
        return setMarks;
        break;
      case 'see' == 'yessee ':
        setMarks(marks + 10);
        return setMarks;
        break;
      case 'identify' == 'yesidentify':
        setMarks(marks + 10);
        return setMarks;
        break;
      case 'colors' == 'colorsyes ':
        setMarks(marks + 10);
        return setMarks;
        break;
      case 'firstword' == 'firstword18 ':
        setMarks(marks + 10);
        return setMarks;
        break;
      default:
        setMarks(marks + 10);
        return setMarks;
        history.push(`/questions/markspage/${marks}`);
    }
  }

  // // calculate marks

  return (
    <div className='container'>
      <div className='row'>
        <div className='col-4'>
          <div className='pb-2 px-3 d-flex flex-wrap align-items-center justify-content-between'>
            <h2>Questions </h2>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className='col-3'></div>
      </div>

      {/* </div> */}
      <div className='row'>
        <h4 className='mb-4'> Questions </h4>
        <form onSubmit={submitMarks}>
          <div>
            <div className='progressCard'>
              <div className='p-3'>
                <h2>1. how many words child talk in a day?</h2>
                <div align='right'>
                  <span>
                    <div className='col-md-8 mb-4'>
                      <div className='form-name'>
                        <div className='form-check form-check-inline'>
                          <input
                            className='form-check-input'
                            type='radio'
                            name='wordday'
                            id='wordless5'
                            value='wordless5'
                            onChange={(e) => setDayWord(e.target.value)}
                          />
                          <label className='form-check-label' for='wordless5'>
                            less 5
                          </label>
                        </div>
                        <div className='form-check form-check-inline'>
                          <input
                            className='form-check-input'
                            type='radio'
                            name='wordday'
                            id='wordmore5'
                            value='wordmore5'
                            onChange={(e) => setDayWord(e.target.value)}
                          />
                          <label className='form-check-label' for='wordmore5'>
                            more than 5
                          </label>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <br></br>
            <div className='progressCard'>
              <div className='p-3'>
                <h2>
                  2. when you show some thing to child then is child watch
                  there?
                </h2>
                <div align='right'>
                  <span>
                    <div className='col-md-8 mb-4'>
                      <div className='form-name'>
                        <div className='form-check form-check-inline'>
                          <input
                            className='form-check-input'
                            type='radio'
                            name='see'
                            id='nosee'
                            value='nosee'
                            required
                            onChange={(e) => setSeeObject(e.target.value)}
                          />
                          <label className='form-check-label' for='PUBLISH'>
                            no
                          </label>
                        </div>
                        <div className='form-check form-check-inline'>
                          <input
                            className='form-check-input'
                            type='radio'
                            name='see'
                            id='yessee'
                            value='yessee'
                            required
                            onChange={(e) => setSeeObject(e.target.value)}
                          />
                          <label className='form-check-label' for='UNPUBLISH'>
                            yes
                          </label>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <br></br>
            <div className='progressCard'>
              <div className='p-3'>
                <h2>3.When you show some thing then is child identify that </h2>
                <div align='right'>
                  <span>
                    <div className='col-md-8 mb-4'>
                      <div className='form-name'>
                        <div className='form-check form-check-inline'>
                          <input
                            className='form-check-input'
                            type='radio'
                            name='identify'
                            id='noidentify'
                            value='noidentify'
                            required
                            onChange={(e) => setIdentifyObject(e.target.value)}
                          />
                          <label className='form-check-label' for='PUBLISH'>
                            no
                          </label>
                        </div>
                        <div className='form-check form-check-inline'>
                          <input
                            className='form-check-input'
                            type='radio'
                            name='identify'
                            id='yesidentify'
                            value='yesidentify'
                            required
                            onChange={(e) => setIdentifyObject(e.target.value)}
                          />
                          <label className='form-check-label' for='UNPUBLISH'>
                            yes
                          </label>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <br></br>
            <div className='progressCard'>
              <div className='p-3'>
                <h2>4. child can identify more than 5 colors</h2>
                <div align='right'>
                  <span>
                    <div className='col-md-8 mb-4'>
                      <div className='form-name'>
                        <div className='form-check form-check-inline'>
                          <input
                            className='form-check-input'
                            type='radio'
                            name='colors'
                            id='colorsno'
                            value='colorsno'
                            required
                            onChange={(e) => setDayWord(e.target.value)}
                          />
                          <label className='form-check-label' for='PUBLISH'>
                            no
                          </label>
                        </div>
                        <div className='form-check form-check-inline'>
                          <input
                            className='form-check-input'
                            type='radio'
                            name='colors'
                            id='colorsyes'
                            value='colorsyes'
                            required
                            onChange={(e) => setDayWord(e.target.value)}
                          />
                          <label className='form-check-label' for='UNPUBLISH'>
                            yes
                          </label>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <br></br>
            <div className='progressCard'>
              <div className='p-3'>
                <h2>5.The first word child told?</h2>
                <div align='right'>
                  <span>
                    <div className='col-md-8 mb-4'>
                      <div className='form-name'>
                        <div className='form-check form-check-inline'>
                          <input
                            className='form-check-input'
                            type='radio'
                            name='firstword'
                            id='firstword19'
                            value='firstword19'
                            required
                            onChange={(e) => setFirstWord(e.target.value)}
                          />
                          <label className='form-check-label' for='firstword19'>
                            after 18 months
                          </label>
                        </div>
                        <div className='form-check form-check-inline'>
                          <input
                            className='form-check-input'
                            type='radio'
                            name='firstword'
                            id='firstword18'
                            value='firstword18'
                            required
                            onChange={(e) => setFirstWord(e.target.value)}
                          />
                          <label className='form-check-label' for='firstword18'>
                            before 18 months
                          </label>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>

        <div className='col-xl-6 mb-4'></div>
        <div>
          <input
            type='submit'
            value='SUBMIT ANSWERS '
            className='form-submit-btn'
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
export default InAnswers;
```

Comment: Can you share more code, or even better create codesandbox for the problem, and share the link in question? It's unclear as to what is `setMarks`, in some case you are using `setMarks`, somewhere you are using `this.setState`, the precise usage of these is unclear.

Comment: if you are using functional component, use 'useState' for managing state, and if using class components use 'this.setState', in the code above i see both

Comment: @JunaidShaikh yeah it's my mistake i edited question

Comment: i dont get the conditions you use in ' case "see" == "yessee "'  , you marks is 0 at first then you check for string in switch case, then adding 10 to it,

Comment: thank you bro for your reply i added the whole code to this question. I hope now you can get idea of my code what I did. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should define the `submit` input inside the `<form>` tag:

```
        <form onSubmit={submitMarks}>
            ...
          <div className='col-xl-6 mb-4'></div>
          <div>
            <input
              type='submit'
              value='SUBMIT ANSWERS '
              className='form-submit-btn'
            />
          </div>
        </form>
```

If you need to calculate the total for `marks` given the responses you should rewrite the `submitMarks` function as:

```
function submitMarks(event) {
  event.preventDefault();  
  var marks = 0;
  if (dayWord === 'wordmore5') marks += 10;
  if (seeObject === 'yessee') marks += 10;
  if (identifyObject === 'yesidentify') marks += 10;
  if (identifyColor === 'colorsyes') marks += 10;
  if (firstWord === 'firstword18') marks += 10;
  history.push(`/questions/markspage/${marks}`);
}
```

No need to declare it `async` nor declare a separate `marks` state variable.

Comment: Thank you bro !!! it's working but always marks is 0. If this all statement true then should display 50. How calculate that total mark in switch?

Comment: @DasunDola Not sure why you are using a `switch` if you want to compare the responses. Check the edited answer if it is the behavior you are looking for.